# how to add button inside input datetime-local datepicker

Tags: reactjs, button, input, datetimepicker

`<input style={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#f1f1f1",border:'none'  }} type="datetime-local" value={moment(cell.text).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")} onChange={(e) => { this.cellDateValueChange(e, cell); }} disabled={cell.nonEditable} onBlur={this.celldataChange}  // onBlur={()=>{console.log("check On Blur")}} ref={this.datepickerInput} />`

[image]

i need to add button inside of input datetime-picker , i am using this on React class based component, if there is any option add button , can you please tell me

need best solution to add button inside the datetime-picker